# Syntax Error with python on module checking

Tags: python

First of all I have to say I have no idea what python is.I just downloaded this file from a site to fix a game but it's not working.All I was able to do was checking the module and keep finding out syntax errors that I don't know how to fix.

```
import glob, struct, os, time

#(frames, offset)
CORRECT_OFFSETS = {
 'z000_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z000_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z000_us.win32.wmp': [(5160, 16)],
 'z002_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z002_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z002_us.win32.wmp': [(3503, 16),
                       (300, 192218060),
                       (3209, 206170072),
                       (2487, 380544968),
                       (4935, 515381728),
                       (2614, 783495996),
                       (3771, 926055480)],
 'z003_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z003_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z003_us.win32.wmp': [(890, 16),
                       (1260, 48459248),
                       (1655, 117355932),
                       (3948, 187336488),
                       (3519, 403805692),
                       (1277, 586686420),
                       (1425, 655754428),
                       (4524, 732863232),
                       (6129, 979373904),
                       (3864, 1312563632)],
 'z004_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z004_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z004_us.win32.wmp': [(2226, 16),
                       (1832, 121399364),
                       (5319, 222033424),
                       (3705, 506525476),
                       (1983, 707701264),
                       (4549, 815726584),
                       (3659, 1061123128),
                       (4544, 1243716124),
                       (6364, 1490772192)],
 'z006_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z006_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z006_us.win32.wmp': [(5575, 16),
                       (2100, 293834120),
                       (550, 387084972),
                       (6079, 416998404),
                       (2799, 743454316),
                       (6280, 894567360),
                       (2669, 1235777764)],
 'z008_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z008_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z008_us.win32.wmp': [(4745, 16),
                       (1636, 259311488),
                       (4017, 348757556),
                       (5056, 561896404),
                       (1792, 836029048),
                       (1338, 932748940),
                       (1498, 1004929368),
                       (2224, 1085833772),
                       (2234, 1206194300),
                       (3768, 1328116396),
                       (5446, 1533012980),
                       (3014, 1828393288),
                       (6379, 1991109064),
                       (7774, 2336102408),
                       (2770, 2757514936)],
 'z010_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z010_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z010_us.win32.wmp': [(2184, 16), (3194, 118867312), (5734, 290475520)],
 'z015_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z015_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z015_us.win32.wmp': [(4103, 16),
                       (4379, 220586552),
                       (280, 456968932),
                       (979, 472130776),
                       (981, 525418388)],
 'z016_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z016_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z016_us.win32.wmp': [(3782, 16),
                       (6480, 183886044),
                       (1859, 535752572),
                       (2834, 637377540),
                       (5100, 792524584),
                       (5179, 1069841780),
                       (4408, 1352921468),
                       (2744, 1592998080)],
 'z017_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z017_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z017_us.win32.wmp': [(1597, 16),
                       (5193, 87344904),
                       (4263, 363545928),
                       (2440, 573049548),
                       (4033, 705570740),
                       (6760, 924508440),
                       (4760, 1291548892)],
 'z018_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z018_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z018_us.win32.wmp': [(1709, 16),
                       (1499, 84767520),
                       (4778, 165357228),
                       (6974, 424118704)],
 'z019_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z019_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z019_us.win32.wmp': [(28887, 16),
                       (5995, 1320322644),
                       (1410, 1638422156),
                       (1670, 1714374168),
                       (2425, 1806044880),
                       (1574, 1937609736),
                       (1650, 2023546760),
                       (1528, 2113553256),
                       (4546, 2197337816),
                       (2218, 2445721012),
                       (7167, 2566140476)],
 'z020_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z020_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z020_us.win32.wmp': [(848, 16)],
 'z021_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z021_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z021_us.win32.wmp': [(3720, 16), (3962, 203966320), (6172, 418886756)],
 'z022_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z022_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z022_us.win32.wmp': [(2747, 16)],
 'z024_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z024_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z024_us.win32.wmp': [(3777, 16), (6448, 203939416)],
 'z027_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z027_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z027_us.win32.wmp': [(814, 16),
                       (7481, 42085708),
                       (1439, 447896256),
                       (1160, 526298144)],
 'z029_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z029_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z029_us.win32.wmp': [(6648, 16),
                       (3403, 362326952),
                       (6980, 549208352),
                       (3994, 930114820),
                       (1470, 1148494148),
                       (6794, 1225595976),
                       (1009, 1596274408),
                       (6009, 1650800068)]}

class BikHeader(object):
    def __init__(self, header):
        self._raw_header = header
        self.sig, self.rev, self.size, self.frames, self.largest_frame, \
        self.frames_again, self.width, self.height, self.frame_dividend, \
        self.frame_divider, self.flags, self.audio = \
            struct.unpack('<3s1sIIIIIIIIII', header)
        self.size += 8

def get_offsets(file):
    data = []
    with open(file, 'rb') as infile:
        infile.seek(16) #WMP header
        while True:
            offset = infile.tell()
            header = infile.read(44)
            if not header: break
            header = BikHeader(header)
            if header.sig not in ('BIK', 'KB2'):
                raise ValueError, "Bad BIK header " + header.sig

            infile.seek(header.size-44, 1)
            header.offset = offset
            data.append(header)
    return data

def realign_this_file(infilename, outfilename, dry=True):
    filebasename = os.path.basename(infilename)
    target_offsets = CORRECT_OFFSETS[filebasename]
    current_offsets = get_offsets(infilename)

    if len(target_offsets) != len(current_offsets):
        raise ValueError, "Unexpected Video Count %s %d != %d" % ( \
            infilename, len(target_offsets), len(current_offsets) )
    if os.path.abspath(infilename) == os.path.abspath(outfilename):
        raise ValueError, "The input and output file can not be the same"

    #The videos in c are not in the same order as r. Using frame count to pair 
    #up the videos correctly.
    offset_lookup = dict(target_offsets)
    if len(offset_lookup) != len(target_offsets):
        raise ValueError, "Multiple videos with the same number of frames"

    MB = 1024**2
    read_size = 16*MB
    head_size = 16 #WMP Header
    if dry:
        for current in current_offsets: #match up videos
            if current.frames not in offset_lookup:
                raise ValueError, "Unable to find matching video"
        print (infilename, outfilename)
        return
    with open(infilename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(outfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
            #write the header
            data = infile.read(head_size)
            outfile.write(data)

            for current in current_offsets:
                #write the video file
                target = offset_lookup[current.frames]
                outfile.seek(target)
                to_write = current.size
                while to_write > 0:
                    to_read = min(to_write, read_size)
                    data = infile.read(to_read)
                    outfile.write(data)
                    to_write -= len(data)
                    print '\r', (infile.tell()/MB), ' Megabytes',
                    if not data:
                        raise ValueError, "End of File at %d with %d bytes left" % (infile.tell(), to_write)
            if target_offsets: print 

def realign_all_files(infolder, outfolder, dry=True):
    filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(infolder, '*.wmp'))
    for file in filelist:
        outfile = os.path.join(outfolder, os.path.basename(file))
        if not dry: print "Processing ", outfile
        realign_this_file(file, outfile, dry)

def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    if not os.path.isdir('orig_movie'):
        raise ValueError, "Missing orig_movie folder"
    if not os.path.isdir('movie'):
        if os.path.exists('movie'):
            raise ValueError, "Unable to create the movie directory due to an existing file call movie.  Please remove that file"
        os.mkdir('movie')

    print "Checking files"
    realign_all_files('orig_movie', 'movie', True) 

    print 
    print "Fixing files"
    realign_all_files('orig_movie', 'movie', False)

    print "Finish. Run time %.2f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Also on dropbox:https://www.dropbox.com/s/hof1qxk6uf8cqw3/z.py?dl=0

P.S: Please, Please be noob friendly,as I said above I have absolutely no idea about python.Thanks.

EDIT:The error happens on line "162" (raise error, bla , bla ,bla ...)

EDIT 2:Now I'm getting this error:

```
>>> 
Checking files
('orig_movie\\z000_1.win32.wmp', 'movie\\z000_1.win32.wmp')
('orig_movie\\z000_1_us.win32.wmp', 'movie\\z000_1_us.win32.wmp')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Mitiden\Final Fantasy XIII\Final Fantasy XIII\white_data\z.py", line 242, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Mitiden\Final Fantasy XIII\Final Fantasy XIII\white_data\z.py", line 233, in main
    realign_all_files('orig_movie', 'movie', True)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Mitiden\Final Fantasy XIII\Final Fantasy XIII\white_data\z.py", line 221, in realign_all_files
    realign_this_file(file, outfile, dry)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Mitiden\Final Fantasy XIII\Final Fantasy XIII\white_data\z.py", line 172, in realign_this_file
    current_offsets = get_offsets(infilename)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Mitiden\Final Fantasy XIII\Final Fantasy XIII\white_data\z.py", line 162, in get_offsets
    raise ValueError("Bad BIK header " + header.sig)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
>>>
```

Comment: That file(module) seems empty.

Comment: What do you mean?I'm seeing it right now.I can upload it elsewhere if you want,Just please help me :/

Comment: Okay I'll just upload it somewhere else

Comment: Try to include actual code here instead of uploading some where else.

Comment: @Tanveer Alam can you give me some help on that?

Comment: Just edit your question and paste your code above.

Comment: Think I did it right this time.Now any ideas?

Comment: Show us exactly what error you are getting.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py when I'm going to check the module it says "Syntax Error ,Invalid Syntax" and then points to the line 162

Comment: @FuriousMathematician Give a complete traceback and also state which version of Python

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry!I don't know what this "traceback" thing is but my python version is "3.4.1"

Comment: @FuriousMathematician That is the problem. The code is written in python 2.7

Comment: @Bhargav Rao so what do I need to do?

Comment: @FuriousMathematician Convert the code to 3.4.1 or use python 2.7. What is your OS?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 (x64)

Comment: @FuriousMathematician Then you will have to convert from python 2 to python 3.

Comment: @BhargavRao So how's that done?And please explain thoroughly since the comments are getting long a bit.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FuriousMathematician I will post the converted code as Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is in python2. So you are getting the error. Use this code:

```
import glob, struct, os, time

#(frames, offset)
CORRECT_OFFSETS = {
 'z000_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z000_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z000_us.win32.wmp': [(5160, 16)],
 'z002_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z002_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z002_us.win32.wmp': [(3503, 16),
                       (300, 192218060),
                       (3209, 206170072),
                       (2487, 380544968),
                       (4935, 515381728),
                       (2614, 783495996),
                       (3771, 926055480)],
 'z003_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z003_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z003_us.win32.wmp': [(890, 16),
                       (1260, 48459248),
                       (1655, 117355932),
                       (3948, 187336488),
                       (3519, 403805692),
                       (1277, 586686420),
                       (1425, 655754428),
                       (4524, 732863232),
                       (6129, 979373904),
                       (3864, 1312563632)],
 'z004_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z004_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z004_us.win32.wmp': [(2226, 16),
                       (1832, 121399364),
                       (5319, 222033424),
                       (3705, 506525476),
                       (1983, 707701264),
                       (4549, 815726584),
                       (3659, 1061123128),
                       (4544, 1243716124),
                       (6364, 1490772192)],
 'z006_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z006_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z006_us.win32.wmp': [(5575, 16),
                       (2100, 293834120),
                       (550, 387084972),
                       (6079, 416998404),
                       (2799, 743454316),
                       (6280, 894567360),
                       (2669, 1235777764)],
 'z008_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z008_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z008_us.win32.wmp': [(4745, 16),
                       (1636, 259311488),
                       (4017, 348757556),
                       (5056, 561896404),
                       (1792, 836029048),
                       (1338, 932748940),
                       (1498, 1004929368),
                       (2224, 1085833772),
                       (2234, 1206194300),
                       (3768, 1328116396),
                       (5446, 1533012980),
                       (3014, 1828393288),
                       (6379, 1991109064),
                       (7774, 2336102408),
                       (2770, 2757514936)],
 'z010_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z010_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z010_us.win32.wmp': [(2184, 16), (3194, 118867312), (5734, 290475520)],
 'z015_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z015_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z015_us.win32.wmp': [(4103, 16),
                       (4379, 220586552),
                       (280, 456968932),
                       (979, 472130776),
                       (981, 525418388)],
 'z016_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z016_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z016_us.win32.wmp': [(3782, 16),
                       (6480, 183886044),
                       (1859, 535752572),
                       (2834, 637377540),
                       (5100, 792524584),
                       (5179, 1069841780),
                       (4408, 1352921468),
                       (2744, 1592998080)],
 'z017_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z017_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z017_us.win32.wmp': [(1597, 16),
                       (5193, 87344904),
                       (4263, 363545928),
                       (2440, 573049548),
                       (4033, 705570740),
                       (6760, 924508440),
                       (4760, 1291548892)],
 'z018_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z018_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z018_us.win32.wmp': [(1709, 16),
                       (1499, 84767520),
                       (4778, 165357228),
                       (6974, 424118704)],
 'z019_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z019_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z019_us.win32.wmp': [(28887, 16),
                       (5995, 1320322644),
                       (1410, 1638422156),
                       (1670, 1714374168),
                       (2425, 1806044880),
                       (1574, 1937609736),
                       (1650, 2023546760),
                       (1528, 2113553256),
                       (4546, 2197337816),
                       (2218, 2445721012),
                       (7167, 2566140476)],
 'z020_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z020_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z020_us.win32.wmp': [(848, 16)],
 'z021_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z021_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z021_us.win32.wmp': [(3720, 16), (3962, 203966320), (6172, 418886756)],
 'z022_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z022_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z022_us.win32.wmp': [(2747, 16)],
 'z024_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z024_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z024_us.win32.wmp': [(3777, 16), (6448, 203939416)],
 'z027_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z027_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z027_us.win32.wmp': [(814, 16),
                       (7481, 42085708),
                       (1439, 447896256),
                       (1160, 526298144)],
 'z029_1.win32.wmp': [],
 'z029_1_us.win32.wmp': [],
 'z029_us.win32.wmp': [(6648, 16),
                       (3403, 362326952),
                       (6980, 549208352),
                       (3994, 930114820),
                       (1470, 1148494148),
                       (6794, 1225595976),
                       (1009, 1596274408),
                       (6009, 1650800068)]}

class BikHeader(object):
    def __init__(self, header):
        self._raw_header = header
        self.sig, self.rev, self.size, self.frames, self.largest_frame, \
        self.frames_again, self.width, self.height, self.frame_dividend, \
        self.frame_divider, self.flags, self.audio = \
            struct.unpack('<3s1sIIIIIIIIII', header)
        self.size += 8

def get_offsets(file):
    data = []
    with open(file, 'rb') as infile:
        infile.seek(16) #WMP header
        while True:
            offset = infile.tell()
            header = infile.read(44)
            if not header: break
            header = BikHeader(header)
            if header.sig not in ('BIK', 'KB2'):
                raise ValueError("Bad BIK header " + header.sig)

            infile.seek(header.size-44, 1)
            header.offset = offset
            data.append(header)
    return data

def realign_this_file(infilename, outfilename, dry=True):
    filebasename = os.path.basename(infilename)
    target_offsets = CORRECT_OFFSETS[filebasename]
    current_offsets = get_offsets(infilename)

    if len(target_offsets) != len(current_offsets):
        raise ValueError("Unexpected Video Count %s %d != %d" % ( \
            infilename, len(target_offsets), len(current_offsets) ))
    if os.path.abspath(infilename) == os.path.abspath(outfilename):
        raise ValueError("The input and output file can not be the same")

    #The videos in c are not in the same order as r. Using frame count to pair 
    #up the videos correctly.
    offset_lookup = dict(target_offsets)
    if len(offset_lookup) != len(target_offsets):
        raise ValueError("Multiple videos with the same number of frames")

    MB = 1024**2
    read_size = 16*MB
    head_size = 16 #WMP Header
    if dry:
        for current in current_offsets: #match up videos
            if current.frames not in offset_lookup:
                raise ValueError("Unable to find matching video")
        print((infilename, outfilename))
        return
    with open(infilename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(outfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
            #write the header
            data = infile.read(head_size)
            outfile.write(data)

            for current in current_offsets:
                #write the video file
                target = offset_lookup[current.frames]
                outfile.seek(target)
                to_write = current.size
                while to_write > 0:
                    to_read = min(to_write, read_size)
                    data = infile.read(to_read)
                    outfile.write(data)
                    to_write -= len(data)
                    print('\r', (infile.tell()/MB), ' Megabytes', end=' ')
                    if not data:
                        raise ValueError("End of File at %d with %d bytes left" % (infile.tell(), to_write))
            if target_offsets: print() 

def realign_all_files(infolder, outfolder, dry=True):
    filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(infolder, '*.wmp'))
    for file in filelist:
        outfile = os.path.join(outfolder, os.path.basename(file))
        if not dry: print("Processing ", outfile)
        realign_this_file(file, outfile, dry)

def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    if not os.path.isdir('orig_movie'):
        raise ValueError("Missing orig_movie folder")
    if not os.path.isdir('movie'):
        if os.path.exists('movie'):
            raise ValueError("Unable to create the movie directory due to an existing file call movie.  Please remove that file")
        os.mkdir('movie')

    print("Checking files")
    realign_all_files('orig_movie', 'movie', True) 

    print() 
    print("Fixing files")
    realign_all_files('orig_movie', 'movie', False)

    print("Finish. Run time %.2f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65912/discussion-on-answer-by-bhargav-rao-syntax-error-with-python-on-module-checking).

Comment: Just post a new question bro... Other's will certainly help. Post with the present code and present error. It is beyond midnight here. I am really sorry, But I can't help. Sorry again

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed for.I'm ever grateful.You surely did a great deal of help.